# Reordering index when mapping arrays with React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, mapping

I'm changing object property inside mapping and I want to change index when object property is `changed ( = input disabled)` , so whats best way to do it?

I've tried making new array for index but can't make it work because then it would need some nested mapping with separate arrays and cant make it work.

edit: I use index to mark text part position in official document, thats why this index is so important.

```
onToggleTextPart = (e, index) => {
    const node = this.myCheckbox[index]
    let newStates = [ ...this.state.meeting_parts ];
    if(node.checked) {
      newStates[index - 1].type_tag = "Included";
    }
    else {
      newStates[index - 1].type_tag = "notIncluded";
      newStates.splice(index-1, 1)

    }
    this.setState({ meeting_parts: newStates });
  }
```

```
return _.map(meeting_parts, (meet, index) => {
      let checked = meet.type_tag === "Included" ? true : false;
      return 
        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="input-group">
            <div className="input-group-prepend">
              <span className="input-group-text minutes-agenda-item-number">
                {index} (THIS is the index i want to change)
              </span>
            </div>
```

I want to i.e when i hide one object from Index 6, it "gives away" its index and Index 7 takes its position.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you actually want to achieve. Do you want index to count up from 1 to n where n is the number of included elements? Also a small tip: `let checked = meet.type_tag === "Included" ? true : false;` is the same as `let checked = meet.type_tag === "Included"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay as far as I understand you want to do this:

```
meeting_parts.filter((meet)=>meet.type_tag === "Included").map((meet, index)=>{
 // your mapping function here
});
```

Filter will return an array of the meetings which type_tag is "Included".

You can read about the [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

EDIT:

```
let includedCount = 0;
meeting_parts.map((meet, index)=>{
  if(meet.type_tag === "Included") {
    includedCount += 1;
  }
  // your mapping function here but use inlcudedCount instead of index
});
```

Of course now it displays some numbers mutpliple times. If you don't want them displayed you have to add logic to disable the rendering when necessary.

Comment: Omg yes! Could be , i try this :)

Comment: almost good, but I want rest of them still visible (this option hides "nonIncluded" . They are input fields that go disabled , but loses their "index" position.. Ive been trying slice array and moving them to last position but that messes up mapping so bad..

Comment: Ah I see. Then it doesn't work like I posted above. I will update my op the way I understand it now.

Comment: ```{meet.type_tag === "Included" && includedCount}```

With this ,it works perfectly. Thanks MUCH!